# Determining the language of a value: Arabic English SQL netezza

Tags: sql, string, netezza

Please I need to specify the language for column values if it is Arabic or English Language, and I a value have a mixed language it will consider as the Arabic Language

I tried the below code to distinguish between the two languages but it didn't work, always gives me `Arabic`

```
SELECT SCRIPT, CASE WHEN script like N'[A-Z]%' THEN 'English' ELSE 'Arabic' END AS LANGUAGE
FROM
    tbl
```

eg:

| Value |
| --- |
| هذا مثال على ذلك |
| This Is Example |
| هذا مجرد Examle |
| يرجى الضغط على الرابط https://www.google.com/ |
| هذا مثال على ذلك 123456 |

The expected results after adding the languages column

| SCRIPT | Language |
| --- | --- |
| هذا مثال على ذلك | Arabic |
| This Is Example | English |
| هذا مجرد Examle | Arabic |
| يرجى الضغط على الرابط https://www.google.com/ | Arabic |
| هذا مثال على ذلك 123456 | Arabic |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regular expressions:

```
SELECT SCRIPT,
       (CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(script, N'^[A-Z]'
             THEN 'English' ELSE 'Arabic'
        END) AS LANGUAGE
FROM tbl
```

I don't believe that Netezza extends `LIKE` to support character ranges.  The above is a regular expression that checks if the first character is in the range A-Z.  I'm not sure that is the best way to determine what you want; but given the logic, you might want to check lower case as well.

EDIT:

If you want *only* English characters for English, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT SCRIPT,
       (CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(script, N'^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$'
             THEN 'English' ELSE 'Arabic'
        END) AS LANGUAGE
FROM tbl
```

You might want to include additional characters if you care about punctuation.

Comment: I think the provided code figure out: If the script starts with the English language it will be distinguished as English, even if it mixed,

Answer (score 1):

If the first character is an indicator of the language, then a more comphrehensive way would be to check for language of your column.

```sql
SELECT c1, 
       CASE 
         WHEN unicode(c1) BETWEEN String_to_int('600', 16) AND string_to_int('6FF', 16)
              OR unicode(c1) BETWEEN string_to_int('750', 16) AND string_to_int('77F', 16)
              OR unicode(c1) BETWEEN string_to_int('8A0', 16) AND string_to_int('8FF', 16)
              -- add more unicode range checks here
          THEN 'Arabic' 
          ELSE 'English' 
       END AS language 
FROM  ... ;
```

This will result in

```
                      C1                       | LANGUAGE
-----------------------------------------------+----------
 هذا مثال على ذلك                              | Arabic
 This Is Example                               | English
 هذا مجرد Examle                               | Arabic
 يرجى الضغط على الرابط https://www.google.com/ | Arabic
 هذا مثال على ذلك 123456                       | Arabic
```

If the use case is a string starting w/ Latin9 / Ascii and then having other unicode characters then using [the unicodes function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5FPD_1.0.0/com.ibm.ips.doc/postgresql/dbuser/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_char_funcs.html) non non-sql post processing might help with more comprehensive solution

```sql
 select unicodes(c1, 32, 'hex') from ..;
```

will give -

```
000647 000630 000627 000020 000645 00062B 000627 000644 000020 000639 000644 000649 000020 000630 000644 000643
 000054 000068 000069 000073 000020 000049 000073 000020 000045 000078 000061 00006D 000070 00006C 000065
 000647 000630 000627 000020 000645 00062C 000631 00062F 000020 000045 000078 000061 00006D 00006C 000065
 00064A 000631 00062C 000649 000020 000627 000644 000636 00063A 000637 000020 000639 000644 000649 000020 000627 000644 000631 000627 000628 000637 000020 000068 000074 000074 000070 000073 00003A 00002F 00002F 000077 000077 000077 00002E 000067 00006F 00006F 000067 00006C 000065 00002E 000063 00006F 00006D 00002F
 000647 000630 000627 000020 000645 00062B 000627 000644 000020 000639 000644 000649 000020 000630 000644 000643 000020 000031 000032 000033 000034 000035 000036
```